# Does the C# method TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime handle DST?

Tags: c#, datetime, dst, datetimeoffset

I have the following list of time zones that a user can choose from, Mountain Standard Time is in there twice for Arizona.  These aren't want they see when they choose.  I pulled this list of a website that had all of Microsofts time zones.  I guess I'm confused if it had Mountain Standard Time listed for the regular states and AZ.

Hawaiian Standard Time

Alaskan Standard Time

Pacific Standard Time

Mountain Standard Time

Mountain Standard Time

Central Standard Time

Central America Standard Time

Eastern Standard Time

U.S. Eastern Standard Time

My question is I'm guessing these don't account for DST, so I'm assuming I need to add something to my conversion to check and see if they're in DST and adjust it accordingly.  Here is how I'm doing the conversion now.

```
TimeZoneInfo time = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(LocationProvider.GetLocation(LocationID).TimeZone.Name);
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, time);
```

Comment: Sad story, smallpox was a disaster.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_Nation#Daylight_Saving_Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `TimeZoneInfo` accounts for DST, so long as you use it properly (which isn't as easy as it might be, admittedly). It's not really clear why you're trying to do what you're doing though...

I know it's confusing that the ID is actually the *standard* ID for the time zone, but it's still a full time zone that knows about DST. It doesn't *just* mean "standard time".

(If you get frustrated with `DateTime` et al and fancy trying [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) for all your date/time needs, I'd be happy to help out :)

Comment: Essentially the servers are in Texas, so when I save something with a time stamp I'm converting it from the time on the server to the local time of the location.

Comment: @Jhorra: Don't do that. Save the *UTC* time, and only convert to local time for display only. Note that local times will end up being ambiguous when clocks go back - *don't* use them where you don't have to.

Comment: That's probably the best way, but either way I still need to do the conversion.  The list I have above has the same time zone for Arizona and all the other states on MST.  How does it know not to convert Arizona's time?

Comment: @Jhorra: It's not clear to me where the list came from - but the two time zones should have different IDs (by definition).

Comment: Ah, the list did have IDs next to them, should I be using that ID and not the name?  Previous examples I found all used the name.

Comment: @Jhorra: You should be using the ID *as an ID*. How you present the zone to the user is a different matter.

Comment: Do you know where I can get a list of time zones with the ID that C# recognizes?  I only need the US time zones for the app.

Comment: @Jhorra: Yes - list all the time zones with `TimeZone.GetSystemTimeZones` and print the `Id` of each. Then you can get it from the id using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`